# How do you convert from a csv to a bag file in ROS?

Tags: ros, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see a lot of things for going from bag to csv, but does anyone know how to go from csv to bag? I am running gmapping but data files in the csv format need to be bag files for gmapping to work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249421/how-do-you-convert-from-a-csv-to-a-bag-file-in-ros?/) by [zb27](https://answers.ros.org/users/28720/zb27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the data do you have in CSV format? You can use the rosbag command to create a bag of your own and it is the preferred option. For tutorials to create a map using gmapping, refer this [map creation](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData)

---

Originally posted by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) with karma: 243 on 2016-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0